# What is wrong with my attempt to save my image?

Tags: python, matplotlib, save, graphic

I am trying to learn Python.  I am using the following program, which creates the image OK, but I want to save it.  I tried some instructions I found on this site, but am getting the error message at the bottom. Any help would be appreciated.

Program:

```
import sys
import random
import matplotlib as plt
from graphics import *

def main():
    m=1
    n=2
    offset=50
    win = GraphWin("MyWin",500, 500)
    win.setBackground(color_rgb(0,0,0))
    for i in range(1,1000,1):
        r= random.uniform(0,1)
        q= int(3*r)
        m = (m/2) + q*(q-1)*75
        n = (n/2) + q*(3-q)*75

        pt = Point(m + offset,n + offset)
        pt.setOutline(color_rgb(255,255,0))
        pt.draw(win)

    print("graphic done")
    plt.savefig("figure.png")
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error Message:

> graphic done
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "fractal_1.py", line 29, in <module>
>       main()
>     File "fractal_1.py", line 24, in main
>       plt.savefig("figure.png")
>   AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'savefig'

Comment: What is your `plt`? It must be a reference to `matplotlib.pyplot` for your code to work.

Answer (score 2):

The call to `plt.savefig("figure.png")` will only work if you have imported as follows:
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

I believe your error lies with `plt` and what it actually references.  If you imported like this:`import matplotlib as plt`
then you would need to call the required function like this: `plt.pyplot.savefig("figure.png")`

If you imported like this:`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`
then you can call the required function like this: `plt.savefig("figure.png")`

Comment: These suggestions did not work.  I am using Python 3.6.3.  I installed matplotlib, and it seemed to install correctly (there were no noted errors).  Is pyplot be included in matplotlib or is that a separate installation? Is matplotlib even what I need since I am not actually making a plot, in the tradional sense?  I am just lighting pixels (a fractal) and want to save the image.  Sorry for the low level of experience, but thanks to all for the help.

Comment: Easy way to check if it is installed correctly is to open terminal and open the python program. Then `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and run the help command on the savefig() function - `help(plt.savefig)`.  Note there is no parenthesis at the end of savefig when using the help function.  If the help is displayed, it is installed properly. This function will also help you answer your question as to if it is the right function to use (I haven't used matplotlib myself)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for including the error, but what that's saying is that `matplotlib` doesn't have a `savefig()` function.

I think it's `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig()` as per this link: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html

Edit your code to say: `plt.pyplot.savefig()`.